# Split (various sized) lines into two columns keeping the first word in a column

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I would like to reformat a text file that contains multiple words by line: each word should be in a separate line, that starts with the first word of the original line.

The original text file looks like this:

```
line1 word1 word2 word3
line2 word4
line3 word5 word6
```

and the expected result should be

```
line1 line1
line1 word1
line1 word2
line1 word3
line2 line2
line2 word4
line3 line3
line3 word5
line3 word6
```

In fact, all the words are the same: there is no difference between the first word of a line and the others, this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14783433/) does not work.

As a beginner in awk, I tried this

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "; OFS="\n"} { x=$1; $1=$1; printf "%s", x "\t" $0 "\n"}'
```

but it results in this

```
line1   line1
word1
word2
word3
line2   line2
word4
line3   line3
word5
word6
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $1,$i}}'  Input_file
```