# I have multiple values per cell in a tsv file, how to split them and match with corresponding value in another column?

Tags: bash, awk, bioinformatics

I have a large .tsv file formatted as such, with many orthogroup rows and species columns but here's just an abbreviated example:

**What I have:**

| Orthogroup | Species1 |
| --- | --- |
| OG001 | S1T1, S1T2, S1T3 |
| OG002 | S1T4 |
| OG003 | S1T5, S1T6 |

I need the comma separated values in the species columns to be split into their own rows, with the corresponding orthogroup pushed to column 1:

**What I want:**

| Orthogroup | Species1 |
| --- | --- |
| OG001 | S1T1 |
| OG001 | S1T2 |
| OG001 | S1T3 |
| OG002 | S1T4 |
| OG003 | S1T5 |
| OG003 | S1T6 |

Again, I have this for approximately 15 species columns and around ~1500 orthogroup rows, and I want to be able to produce an output like above for each species column. I have tried many awk commands but cannot seem to get it to work.

Thank you so m uch in advance!

Comment: This might help: [Split (various sized) lines into two columns keeping the first word in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56794542/3776858)

Comment: [edit] your question to replace those graphical tables with the raw, plain text that you created them from so your question is clearer, less ambiguous and we have something we can copy/paste to test a potential solution against. Also add your own attempt to solve the problem. Once you do that then we can come up with the best solution for you, otherwise you might get a solution to a problem you don't actually have.

Comment: dawg has provided an answer but now you've stated you need to run his code for multiple columns; please update the question with an example of 2-3 sample input columns (of species?) and the associated (desired) output

Comment: How are you proposing that another column be delineated heading and column wise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what is described:

```
awk  '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
FNR==1{print; next}
{
   split($2, rows, /, /)
   for(i=1; i<=length(rows); i++)
       print($1, rows[i])
}
' file.tsv
```

Prints:

```
Orthogroup  Species1
OG001   S1T1
OG001   S1T2
OG001   S1T3
OG002   S1T4
OG003   S1T5
OG003   S1T6
```

Suppose not you have multiple columns, you can loop over them and loop over the splits.

Given:

```
cat file.tsv
Orthogroup  Species1    Species2    Species3
OG001   S1T1, S1T2, S1T3    ST1B, ST1C  ST1D
OG002   S1T4    ST2B, ST2C  ST2D
OG003   S1T5, S1T6  ST3B
```

Try:

```
awk  '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
FNR==1{print; next}
{
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        split($i, rows, /, /)
        for(j=1; j<=length(rows); j++) {
            s=""
            for(k=1; k<i; k++)
                s=s OFS
            print($1 s rows[j])
        }
    }
}
' file.tsv
```

With that example, prints:

```
Orthogroup  Species1    Species2    Species3
OG001   S1T1
OG001   S1T2
OG001   S1T3
OG001       ST1B
OG001       ST1C
OG001           ST1D
OG002   S1T4
OG002       ST2B
OG002       ST2C
OG002           ST2D
OG003   S1T5
OG003   S1T6
OG003       ST3B
```

Comment: Phenomenal! Any idea of how to loop this over all of my columns? Right now it only does this for column 2.

Comment: Use a loop for the number of fields. If you use a better example, you will get a better answer.